# JMESPath to flatten complicated query array results

Tags: json, jmespath

Given the JSON

```json
{
  "Reservations": [
    {
      "Groups": [],
      "Instances": [
        {
          "AmiLaunchIndex": 0,
          "ImageId": "ami-0abcdef1234567890",
          "InstanceId": "i-1234567890abcdef0",
          "InstanceType": "t2.micro",
          "KeyName": "MyKeyPair",
          "LaunchTime": "2018-05-10T08:05:20.000Z",
          "Monitoring": {
            "State": "disabled"
          },
          "Placement": {
            "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-2a",
            "GroupName": "",
            "Tenancy": "default"
          },
          "PrivateDnsName": "ip-10-0-0-157.us-east-2.compute.internal",
          "PrivateIpAddress": "10.0.0.157",
          "ProductCodes": [],
          "PublicDnsName": "",
          "State": {
            "Code": 0,
            "Name": "pending"
          },
          "StateTransitionReason": "",
          "SubnetId": "subnet-04a636d18e83cfacb",
          "VpcId": "vpc-1234567890abcdef0",
          "Architecture": "x86_64",
          "BlockDeviceMappings": [],
          "ClientToken": "",
          "EbsOptimized": false,
          "Hypervisor": "xen",
          "NetworkInterfaces": [
            {
              "Attachment": {
                "AttachTime": "2018-05-10T08:05:20.000Z",
                "AttachmentId": "eni-attach-0e325c07e928a0405",
                "DeleteOnTermination": true,
                "DeviceIndex": 0,
                "Status": "attaching"
              },
              "Description": "",
              "Groups": [
                {
                  "GroupName": "MySecurityGroup",
                  "GroupId": "sg-0598c7d356eba48d7"
                }
              ],
              "Ipv6Addresses": [],
              "MacAddress": "0a:ab:58:e0:67:e2",
              "NetworkInterfaceId": "eni-0c0a29997760baee7",
              "OwnerId": "123456789012",
              "PrivateDnsName": "ip-10-0-0-157.us-east-2.compute.internal",
              "PrivateIpAddress": "10.0.0.157",
              "PrivateIpAddresses": [
                {
                  "Primary": true,
                  "PrivateDnsName": "ip-10-0-0-157.us-east-2.compute.internal",
                  "PrivateIpAddress": "10.0.0.157"
                }
              ],
              "SourceDestCheck": true,
              "Status": "in-use",
              "SubnetId": "subnet-04a636d18e83cfacb",
              "VpcId": "vpc-1234567890abcdef0",
              "InterfaceType": "interface"
            }
          ],
          "RootDeviceName": "/dev/xvda",
          "RootDeviceType": "ebs",
          "SecurityGroups": [
            {
              "GroupName": "MySecurityGroup",
              "GroupId": "sg-0598c7d356eba48d7"
            }
          ],
          "SourceDestCheck": true,
          "StateReason": {
            "Code": "pending",
            "Message": "pending"
          },
          "Tags": [],
          "VirtualizationType": "hvm",
          "CpuOptions": {
            "CoreCount": 1,
            "ThreadsPerCore": 1
          },
          "CapacityReservationSpecification": {
            "CapacityReservationPreference": "open"
          },
          "MetadataOptions": {
            "State": "pending",
            "HttpTokens": "optional",
            "HttpPutResponseHopLimit": 1,
            "HttpEndpoint": "enabled"
          }
        }
      ],
      "OwnerId": "123456789012",
      "ReservationId": "r-02a3f596d91211712"
    }
  ]
}
```

and the JMESPath query

```
Reservations[].Instances[].{KeyName: KeyName, InstanceId: InstanceId, GroupId: NetworkInterfaces[].Groups[].GroupId, SubnetId: NetworkInterfaces[].SubnetId}
```

it will yield:

```json
[
  {
    "KeyName": "MyKeyPair",
    "InstanceId": "i-1234567890abcdef0",
    "GroupId": [
      "sg-0598c7d356eba48d7"
    ],
    "SubnetId": [
      "subnet-04a636d18e83cfacb"
    ]
  }
]
```

How can I just get *the first item* of the arrays, and flatten the final result to:

```json
[
  {
    "KeyName": "MyKeyPair",
    "InstanceId": "i-1234567890abcdef0",
    "GroupId": "sg-0598c7d356eba48d7",
    "SubnetId": "subnet-04a636d18e83cfacb"
  }
]
```

I tried to place `0` into those `[]`s (like `GroupId: NetworkInterfaces[0].Groups[0].GroupId[0]`), or use `GroupId: NetworkInterfaces[].Groups[].GroupId[]`, but nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your actual attempts are not working because you trying to address some properties as arrays.

In your attempt

```
NetworkInterfaces[0].Groups[0].GroupId[0]
```

`NetworkInterfaces` and `Groups` are indeed arrays, so you need to address them with an array notation. But the resulting group is an object and `GroupId` is one of its property.

So, you'll need to address it using

```
NetworkInterfaces[0].Groups[0].GroupId
```

The exact same goes for `SubnetId`.

So, the end query would be:

```
Reservations[].Instances[].{
  KeyName: KeyName, 
  InstanceId: InstanceId, 
  GroupId: NetworkInterfaces[0].Groups[0].GroupId, 
  SubnetId: NetworkInterfaces[0].SubnetId
}
```

That yields your expected:

```json
[
  {
    "KeyName": "MyKeyPair",
    "InstanceId": "i-1234567890abcdef0",
    "GroupId": "sg-0598c7d356eba48d7",
    "SubnetId": "subnet-04a636d18e83cfacb"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the first item from the pipe, e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ Interfaces|json_query('[].Groups[].GroupId | [0]') }}"
      vars:
        Interfaces:
          - Groups:
              - GroupId: sg-0598c7d356eba48d7
                GroupName: MySecurityGrou
```

Comment: Hmm... for me it is as simple as running `aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[]...
`, but I understand you might not have access to aws cli, so I prepare the full return string from `aws ec2 describe-instances`. This is IMHO already a minimal reproducible example, as A) further simplify the test string will no longer applicable to the aws ec2 describe-instances case (the answer would no longer be plug-n-play-able), and B) further simplify the final expected result is literately changing OP to an entirely different question.

Comment: So I guess the conclusion to OP, which asked for GroupId & SubnetId both to be flattened in the final result, so all four fields including the KeyNam & InstanceId are all simple strings, is that it is impossible to do so, right?